# How to fetch unique values from two tables in sql?

Tags: sql-server

`Table1`:

```
id  name  design  AddrId
1   Ram   SE        101
2   Ravi  JSE       102
3   Vas   SSE       103
```

`Table2`:

```
AddrId   MobNo   EmailId 
101      78945   a@gmail
101      54675   b@gmail
102      12345   c@gmail
103      45687   d@gmail 
103      64587   d@gmail
```

In second table I have duplicate values. I need only unique values. like here I have two different addresses with same ID, so can I get first one. I need all values(unique) from first and second tables. can any one help this.

Comment: Which rows do you want to keep and which ones to eliminate from the second table?

Comment: Do you want to query both the table separately or you want to join both the tables??

Comment: first row should keep and second one should eliminate.. @Rachcha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with Row_Number

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AddrId ORDER BY AddrId ASC) AS RN 
FROM TABLE1 
     JOIN TABLE2 ON
     TABLE1.AddrId =TABLE2.AddrId
) AS T

WHERE RN = 1
```

## [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)